Grouping log entries by request in Google Cloud with C#
I have a C# .NET 8 application running on Google Cloud Run.
To better troubleshoot issues, I would like to group or search log by either:

Logs happening during the same request
Logs for the same user -- the endpoints are authenticated
Some other custom label or span or trace

This would help me search and group entries in the Google Log Explorer, so I can better understand what has happened in one request / for one user.
How can I achieve this using the Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore3?
